# Service Automatic Called on Destroying Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-intentservice

I am stuck with the problem of **`Activity + Service`** in that I have following number of Activities and Services.

#### Activities:

> LoginActivity => OrderListActivity => AddOrderActivity => ConfirmOrderActivity

#### Services:

1. **ReceivingOrderService** - Receiving New Data From Server
2. **SendingOrderService** - Sending new Data to Server

Above both Service Calling from another Separate Service on duration of some **interval**.

3. **CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder** - To call ReceivingOrderService (Interval 15Mins)
4. **CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder** - To call SendingOrderService (Interval 3Mins)

#### CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder:

```
public class CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder extends Service {

    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "RECEIVING OLD TIMER CANCELLED>>>");
        }

        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if(getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME).exists())
                        startService(new Intent(CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder.this, ReceivingOrderService.class));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection not available");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60000); // 1000*60*15 = 9,00,000 = 15 minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        if(timer != null)
            timer.cancel();

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Receiving...");
    }
}
```

#### CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder:

```
public class CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder extends Service {

    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "OLD TIMER CANCELLED>>>");
        }

        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, ">>>>>>>> SENDING AUTO SYNC SERVICE >>>>>>>>");
                if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if(getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME).exists())
                        startService(new Intent(CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder.this, SendingOrderService.class));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connection not available");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 120000); //  1000*120*15 = 1,800,000 = 15 minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        if(timer != null)
            timer.cancel();

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Sending...");
    }
}
```

#### ConfirmOrderActivity#Final Task which i have called for Insert Data:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                ConfirmOrderProductActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Inserting "
                + (isInquiry ? "Inquiry" : "Order") + "...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog
                .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int account_id = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_DATA,
                MODE_APPEND).getInt(DATA_ACCOUNT_ID, 0);

        /**
         * Check Whether isInquiry or not...
         */
        product_type = isWeight ? 1 : 0;
        if (isInquiry) {
            /*
             * INSERTING DATA IN INQUIRY TABLE
             */
            return m_inquiry_id;
        } else {
            /*
             * INSERTING DATA IN ORDER TABLE
             */
            return m_order_id;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer m_order_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(m_order_id);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (dbHelper.db.isOpen())
            dbHelper.close();

        String title = "Retry";
        String message = "There is some problem, Go Back and Try Again";

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ConfirmOrderProductActivity.this);

        if (m_order_id != -1) {
            title = isInquiry ? "New Inquiry" : "New Order";
            message = isInquiry ? "Your Inquiry Send Successfully." : "Your Order Saved Successfully.";
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.success).setCancelable(false);
        } else {
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.fail).setCancelable(false);
        }

        alert.setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                ConfirmOrderProductActivity.this,
                                FragmentChangeActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

                        /* Opening Left to Right Animation */
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_out,
                                R.anim.right_in);
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}.execute();
```

**Everything is working fine as per flow of inserting records in database.**

## After Adding Inquiry:

[image]

## Destroying Activity and Getting following Logcat:

[image]

### **Main Problem:**

When I placed  order successfully from **ConfirmOrderActivity**, It is displaying `AlertDialog` of **Success** Message which is **cancellable** `false`. When I Stop application from this Activity, **Its calling both `CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder` and `CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder` automatically.**

#### Edited:

> I am calling both Service from `LoginActivity` only, after that it
>   will called automatically after given intervals But Problem occurs
>   when I destroy **ConfirmOrderActivity** when dialog is shown.

I didn't know why it happens that Why its running automatically when I stop Activity Directly.

### I have tried `onStartCommand()` with `START_NON_STICKY` in `Service` but not working. (as **`START_STICKY`** is default.)

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you stopped the service when the activity is destroyed?

Comment: No, @ajantha I dont have used `onDestroy` or `onStop` any methods. and Its calling automatically, Not Stopping.

Comment: Try to unbind and destroy the service while your activity is destroyed.

Comment: @ajantha I want to keep its call on given intervals so i cant do that. But i dont know why its calling when i destroy activity.

Comment: If the services live for just as long as the activities - you are using services wrong and they are not needed. This will simplify your code

Comment: @MsYvette I have posted task of that activity which is inserting record in database.

Answer (score 4):

You need to either run your [service in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) so when the activity is destroyed so will the service or use a bound service and manage the binding with the activity lifecycle, so it is not continually restarted when the activity is destroyed.

From this android docs tutorial [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

You need to do this for each service.

```
public class CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder getService() {
        return CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder.this;
    }
}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
```

From your activity that creates and calls the service, that when it is destroyed you want your service destroyed.

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    CheckAutoSyncReceivingOr mService;
    boolean mBound = false;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to CheckAutoSyncReceivingOr
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckAutoSyncReceivingOr.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to CheckAutoSyncReceivingOr, cast the IBinder and get CheckAutoSyncReceivingOr instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

And manage the [service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle). Restart the same service with your timer, do not create a new service.

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
    int mStartMode;       // indicates how to behave if the service is killed
    IBinder mBinder;      // interface for clients that bind
    boolean mAllowRebind; // indicates whether onRebind should be used

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The service is being created
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
        return mStartMode;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // A client is binding to the service with bindService()
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // All clients have unbound with unbindService()
        return mAllowRebind;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        // A client is binding to the service with bindService(),
        // after onUnbind() has already been called
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // The service is no longer used and is being destroyed
    }
}
```

Note `START_NOT_STICKY` will only prevent the service from restarting if the device is low on memory.

Be mindful that you where you are starting services, just start it once and allow the service to maintain it's own lifecycle until you destroy it with your activity.

This is in reply to your original unedited question, when the app was mysteriously crashing:

You need to destroy the dialog before the context window the dialog is attached to. That will cause a problem. So this is where program flow and the order of closing and cleaning up resources is important. They, frequently have to be destroyed in the reverse order they were created if they are dependent upon parent windows (which is often in the form of a particular activity).

It's difficult to trace your code, so this is a generic answer.

Make use of onPause and onDestroy in your activities.

In all your activities, manage any resources you have created within that activity and with a null check, close them down. Like you have in your service class. If you want to override the parent onDestroy, place your custom code before super.onDestroy.

```
protected void onDestroy() {

    if(timer != null)
        timer.cancel();

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Sending...");

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about `instances running and may need to pass a single application context throughout your app`?

Comment: I have tried `START_NOT_STICKY` and other options also. It doesn't work.

Comment: Its not like that dear. I had given bounty to that user who has first answered me which is 50% useful me. you have told about services after he said. so i had given him. Thank you for your effort. You are appreciable really.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)For Your Dialog:**

The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the `Dialog` you created  before exiting the `Activity`, e.g. in `onDestroy()`. All **Windows & Dialog** should be closed before leaving an `Activity`.

**(2)For Your service autostart:**

you have to look at the value the service returns from its onStartCommand method. The default value is START_STICKY which will restart the service after it is destroyed. Take a look at the [onStartCommand documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) for more details:

Comment: 2nd Solution not working for me. Is there any other solution>

Answer (score 1):

Services got killed when application got killed (add logs in service `onStartCommand()` and `onDestroy()` function and try clearing app from recent list and you will see `onDestroy()` is called. Android will re-start service if you have returned `START_STICKY` intent in `onStartCommand()`).

There are two approaches to fix your problem.

1. Either make your two services as [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).
2. Instead of using `CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder` and `CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder` to schedule start of another services, you should use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to schedule your task.

Answer (score 1):

If the process that runs your service gets killed, the Android system will restart it automatically it is default behavior.

This behavior is defined by the return value of `onStartCommand()` in your Service implementation. The constant `START_NOT_STICKY` tells Android not to restart the service if it s running while the process is "killed".

You need to Override method `onStartCommand()` in your service class and move all your code from `onStart()` method to `onStartCommand()` method.

According to the Android Documentation:

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of
>   operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they
>   return from `onStartCommand()`: `START_STICKY` is used for services that
>   are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while `START_NOT_STICKY`
>   or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` are used for services that should only
>   remain running while processing any commands sent to them

`onStart()` method calls each time when service is restarted but `onStartCommand()` method will not called if you return `START_NON_STICKY`.

Don't use onStart() anymore, it's deprecated.

I hope it helps you.