# Service with Timer calling another Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-timer

I am managing data from **Server to Client** and **Client to Server** using `Service`. In that I am calling one `Service` after Login:

```
context.startService(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder.class));
context.startService(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder.class));
```

I have called one timer in above both `Service`

#### CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder Service:

> Its calling another service named `ReceivingOrderService` on Every 1
>   minute to get updated data from server.

```
public class CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder extends Service {

    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder Binding Service...");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "RECEIVING OLD TIMER CANCELLED>>>");
        }

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "<<<<<<<<< RECEIVING AUTO SYNC SERVICE <<<<<<<<");
                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if (getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME).exists())
                        startService(new Intent(
                                CheckAutoSyncReceivingOrder.this,
                                ReceivingOrderService.class));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection not available");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60000); // 1000*60 = 60000 = 1 minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (timer != null)
            timer.cancel();

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Receiving...");

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

#### CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder Service:

> Its calling another service named `SendingOrderService` on Every 2.5
>   minute to send updated data to server.

```
public class CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder extends Service {

    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "OLD TIMER CANCELLED>>>");
        }

        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, ">>>>>>>> SENDING AUTO SYNC SERVICE >>>>>>>>");
                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if (getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME).exists())
                        startService(new Intent(CheckAutoSyncSendingOrder.this,
                                SendingOrderService.class));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connection not available");
                }
            }
        }, 0, 150000); // 1000*60 = 60000 = 1 minutes * 2.5 = 2.5 =>Minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (timer != null)
            timer.cancel();

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Sending...");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Both Activity will running till Internet off. It will automatically call again when Internet Connection Available.

Main thing is I am getting problem **While destroying activity services calls automatically**.

Is there any solution or way to change flow for same thing?

Advance Thanking you.

Comment: Its sub-classes of `IntentService` [I have posted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529544/service-automatic-called-on-destroying-activity) but i think my problem is with flow so i have posted again.

Comment: I have explain it in my [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529544/service-automatic-called-on-destroying-activity)

Comment: I just solved problem of error log in which i am getting error of `token` null, but i am still getting problem with service which is called on destroying activity.

Comment: I dont have overrides any other methods excepting `onCreate()`

Comment: @PratikButani have you used IntentService instead of Service? if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice you can find that Service runs in background but it runs on the Main Thread of the application so if main thread is destroyed service will restart so you need to use IntentService and override onStartCommand(Intent, int, int), move all your implementation code to this method and return START_NOT_STICKY in that method

Comment: @Rajesh You are right. There is one problem. If I implement `IntentService` then it will be destroy automatically and my `timer` will be stop on destroying. so I can use it as your way. Is there any other way instead service which keep timer on/off.

Comment: have you used START_NOT_STICKY  in IntentService and move all your code from onStart() to onStartCommand()?

Comment: i have exactly done this way and it is working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IntentService` instead of `Service`.

- The `Service` runs in background but it runs on the Main Thread of the application.
- The `IntentService` runs on a separate worker thread.

If the process that runs your service gets killed, the Android system will restart it automatically it is default behavior.

so if Activity's Main thread is destroyed service will restart but if you use `IntentService` and use `START_NOT_STICKY` then it will not restart your services.

This behavior is defined by the return value of `onStartCommand()` in your Service implementation. The constant `START_NOT_STICKY` tells Android not to restart the service if it s running while the process is "killed".

You need to Override method `onStartCommand()` in your service class and move all your code from `onStart()` method to `onStartCommand()` method.

According to the Android Documentation:

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of
>   operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they
>   return from `onStartCommand()`: `START_STICKY` is used for services that
>   are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while `START_NOT_STICKY`
>   or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` are used for services that should only
>   remain running while processing any commands sent to them

`onStart()` method calls each time when service is restarted but `onStartCommand()` method will not called if you return `START_NON_STICKY`.

For more details of difference between `IntentService` and `Service`. you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: One question is raise in my mind that When `IntentService` is destroyed `onDestroy()` will call and `myTimer` will stop. Then How it will start again. How it will work?

Comment: Do you want services to continue or stop services when Activity is being destroyed ?

Comment: I want to continue running service because of Timer. I dont want to stop that when activity is being destroyed. I have stopped programmatically that Service when i don't need.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService):

> When a service is started, it has a lifecycle that's independent of the component that started it and the service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed. As such, the service should stop itself when its job is done by calling stopSelf(), or another component can stop it by calling stopService().

Since you *"dont have overrides any other methods excepting onCreate()"* in the `Activity` in question, you might experience the following:

1. `Service`'s `onDestroy()` won't be called unless another app component call `stopService()`;
2. that said results in `Timer` keep executing its job.

Stop the services as per the documentation.

**Edit (with respect to your comment):**

*"its starting new job when i destroy activity"* means the system killed the service and, since you haven't overridden `onStartCommand()` whose default return value is `START_STICKY`, the service has been recreated and its `onStart()` method has been called.

You **cannot** change such a system behaviour. But you can run the service in [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

Comment: But why its starting new job when i destroy activity. I don't want stop services because its background sync process of my app.