# service that will die with activity

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I need a service that will be destroyed when activity is destroyed.
the problem is that activities onDestroyed is not always called and I want the service to keep running if the user press home and the activity status is onStop.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249861/stop-service-in-activity-ondestroy